# Having a different version of a dependency based on a conan profile

Tags: c++, gcc, googletest, conan

We have several projects for an embedded Linux environments. We are switching to Conan for our dependency management. The shared libraries for these projects are turned into conan packages. These packages are build for multiple platforms using the same code base. For these projects we use googletest as our unit testing framework.

For these embedded environments we are tied to the cross compilers delivered to us by our supplier. We are tied to gcc 4.4.3 and 5.2.0 to cross compile our code resulting in different behaviour building packages. As we are using googletest I cross compile a version of googletest and add it to my artifactory so dependencies can be resolved. I just made a simple conanfile.py for googletest to build it calling the normal cmake, but unfortunately I can't build the 1.8.1 and 1.10.0 version using the gcc 4.4.3 cross compiler.

Possible solutions:

1. Keep using 1.8.0 version of googletest for every project. Possible, but with the disadvantage not being able to use new googletest features.
2. No unit tests when using the gcc 4.4.2 profile. Possible, but due to the fact we defined a test_package it wants to build unit tests. We can work around is to specify a non existing test folder when creating the package. But that means a different command to for creating a package.
3. Use version 1.8.0 when building for the gcc 4.4.3 profile and use a newer version for other profiles. Possible?

Although building for different platforms I have on code base and one conanfile.py to define the package. Using the --profile options I cross compile for different architectures. I would like to keep it this way.

I tried specifying the version of the googletest package as [>=1.8.0] in the hope that for the gcc 4.4.3 profile it picks up the 1.8.0 version as that is the only version with binaries for that architecture. Unfortunately it finds the newer versions and throws an error that it is missing the prebuilt package for the newer version.

How can I make one profile use version 1.8.0 of a dependency an make the other profile use version 1.10.0 for the dependency?

One thing I want to prevent is to do checks based on profile settings in my conanfile.py, as that would create a dependency between the files. This may cause me to change the conanfile.py when adding or removing profiles in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use version 1.8.0 when building for the gcc 4.4.3 profile and use a newer version for other profiles. Possible?

Yes, totally possible.

But first you need to understand that test_package is not for your project unit test. Tests packages are created to validate your package only. If you want to test your project using Conan, it should be done during the build step:

```py
class LibConan(ConanFile):
    ...

    def build_requirements(self):
        if self.settings.compiler == "gcc" and tools.Version(self.settings.compiler.version) < "5":
            self.build_requires("gtest/1.8.1")
        elif self.settings.compiler == "gcc":
            self.build_requires("gtest/1.10.1")

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()
        if self.develop:
            cmake.test()
```

You can obtain more information about [develop](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#develop) and [unit test](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/methods.html#unit-testing-your-library) in [Conan docs](https://docs.conan.io).

Now about this example, `build_requirements` installs the GTest package according your compiler version and its name, in this case, GCC < 5. Besides that, `self.develop` is only available when building the package (conan create command), thus the unit tests only runs when creating, not when installing.

Comment: The question was asked  because I want to solve this in the test_package of a conan package I create. The unit tests in test_package depends on a gtest package, so I need to switch during the build of the test_package to the correct version.

This answer does point in the right direction as I can add a build_requirements step to the test_package/conanfile.py and have it switch correctly.

Comment: Again, test_package was not designed for testing your project, this is not the correct way. If you want to test it, use the build step. That's why the test package is totally separated, it simulates a consumer which uses your generated package. Do not add build_requirements in test_package and use it for unit tests.

Comment: I've read up on the subject and understand the difference between test_package and testing the project. The concept i am presenting does work, when calling the create command I run the unit tests from my test_package and also validating it can be consumed at the same time. I will change my solution to using the cmake.test() way. I will run into the same problem, so thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly declare `build_requires` in profiles, something like:

```
[settings]
compiler=gcc
compiler.version=4.4.3

[build_requires]
gtest/1.8.0
```

And

```
[settings]
compiler=gcc
compiler.version=5.2.0

[build_requires]
gtest/1.10.0
```

These build requires are applied to all packages that need to be built, but you can also define which packages do they apply to. You can check in the recipes whether this build-requires is used, and if your profile doesn't declare gtest as build-requires, then skip testing.

Check https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/profiles.html